# Django - How do I use the associated model of the modelForm in queryset to the form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

How do I access the model object associated in a ModelForm? Something like self.Meta.model? My model and form are defined as below, where I am trying to accessing the model's attribute by "self.Meta.model.attribute", but this doesn't work.

```
class Attribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class AttributeIndex(models.Model):
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product)
    attribute = models.ManyToManyField(Attribute)

class AttributeIndexForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = AttributeIndex  
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AttributeIndexForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['attribute'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=self.Meta.model.attribute.all, widget=widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple("Attributes", is_stacked=False))
```

Comment: Why do you need to do that? It might not be the most straightforward way to achieve what you need.

Comment: There are many attributes, and a product have about 20 attributes but only a few attributes that will be used for searching products. And in the form, I want users can only select the attribute associated with the product to decide which of them will be used for search, which is the AttributeIndex. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that "self.instance" works, which is exactly what I want:

```
 self.fields['attribute'].queryset = self.instance.attribute.all()
```

Comment: Yes but keep in mind that `instance` is only available when you do `MyModelForm(instance=model_instance)` and not when you instantiate an empty form with `MyModelForm()`.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a Model with

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        something = 'foo'
```

or a ModelForm with

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

there is a special [metaclass](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#__metaclass__) that upon "reading" your class definition, among
other things, it sets/replaces the `Meta` attribute as `_meta`.

So in order to access the associated model in your ModelForm do:

```
AttributeIndexForm._meta.model
```

But in your particular situation where you just want to customize the queryset of
the `attribute` field you should do:

```
class AttributeIndexForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = AttributeIndex  
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AttributeIndexForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['attribute'].queryset = Attribute.objects.filter(..condition..)
        self.fields['attribute'].widget = widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple("Attributes", is_stacked=False))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. From your help, I was able to figure out that self.instance is really what I wanted. Thanks.